# Is Homeo$(X)$ metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space then is Homeo$(X)$ (the group of homeomorphisms of $X$ with itself) endowed with the [compact open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) metrizable?

At first I thought I could define a metric on Homeo$(X)$ using the metric $d$ but I can't find a good way to do that. I am not certain how to prove Homeo$(X)$ is regular and has a countable basis either.

If this question can't be answered in general then can it be done in the case when $X$ is  connected, locally path connected and locally compact?

Thank you.

Comment: In general no: for example, space of homeomorphisms of the real line is not normal; and hence not metrisable.

Comment: This satisfies your additional conditions; so these restrictions don't allow a metric to be given there either.

Comment: where can I find a proof for the fact that Homeo$(\mathbb{R})$ is not normal?

Comment: If $X$ is compact it's just the sup metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let $(X,d)$ be an uncountable set equipped with the discrete metric. The space $Homeo(X,d)$ is the set of bijections $X\to X$. The compact-open topology on this space is simply the topology of pointwise convergence, i.e., the subspace topology induced by the product topology on $X^X$. From this, it is easy to see that $Homeo(X,d)$  is not 1st countable and, hence, not metrizable. On the other hand, according to

Robert A. McCoy, Ibula Ntantu, *Topological Properties of Spaces of Continuous Functions*, Springer Lecture Notes in Math, Volume 1315 (1988), page 68,

for a metrizable space $X$, the space of continuous functions $C(X,X)$ (equipped with the compact-open topology) is metrizable iff $X$ is *hemicompact*, i.e. contains a countable collection of compact subsets $C_n\subset X$ such that every compact in $X$ is contained in some $C_n$. Thus, for example $Homeo({\mathbb R}, {\mathbb R})$ is metrizable (I am not sure where did the statement by Mozibur Ullah come from), since it is a subspace of a metrizable space.